# Sharing the value of a Node.JS variable with a Node.js deamon?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, sorry, I feel the titles not that great, I am coding a little application in javascript, the way I planned it all out is, I have a client and a deamon, the client will be a simple:

```
 var prompt = require("sync-prompt").prompt,
 input = prompt("What is it you are after? "),
```

But, I am stuck on how to send value of the input variable to a deamon, or just another node.js script running constantly, how can I use the input variable in the deamon once its sent? Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

they are running on separate machines.

Comment: running on the same machine, or on different machines?

Comment: The deamon would be ran on a server, the client would be ran by the user. Sorry, I should have added that.

Comment: You need to use some socket communication. Which one is probably off topic for SO, since it's considered a recommendation. Maybe look into socket.io, net, or using http.

Comment: I will do that, thank you!